# Loading plain text dates in Spark v3 from CSV

Tags: java, csv, apache-spark, date, data-ingestion

I am trying to ingest a very basic CSV file with dates in Apache Spark. The complexity resides in the months being spelled out. For analytics purposes, I'd like to have those months as a date. Here is my CSV file:

```
Period,Total
"January 2000","5394"
"February 2000","5249"
"March 2000","6447"
"April 2000","6062"
"May 2000","6342"
"June 2000","6914"
```

I try to ingest the data using:

```
// Creates the schema
StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[] {
    DataTypes.createStructField(
        "month",
        DataTypes.DateType,
        false),
    DataTypes.createStructField(
        "ct",
        DataTypes.IntegerType,
        true) });

// Reads a CSV file with header
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().format("csv")
    .option("header", true)
    .option("dateFormat", "MMMM YYYY")
    .schema(schema)
    .load("my.csv");
```

Spark does not really like the `dateFormat` I use... and gives me:

org.apache.spark.SparkUpgradeException: You may get a different result due to the upgrading of Spark 3.0: Fail to recognize 'YYYY' pattern in the DateTimeFormatter. 1) You can set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy to LEGACY to restore the behavior before Spark 3.0. 2) You can form a valid datetime pattern with the guide from https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html

I tried `LLLL YYYY`, `M Y`, `MMMM Y`... `LLLL YYYY` does not crash but returns a null field.

I use Spark v3.1, Java v8. Java is not the problem here ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uppercase letter `Y` is week year pattern, not year pattern. You should use lowercase `y` letters for pattern.

So your pattern should be `MMMM yyyy` instead of `MMMM YYYY`:

```java
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().format("csv")
    .option("header", true)
    .option("dateFormat", "MMMM yyyy")
    .schema(schema)
    .load("my.csv");
```

Comment: lol - of course it is :) I must have had something in my eyes and I was LOOKING at https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html... Thanks Vincent!